# Min and Max C Failure

Tags: c, arrays, max, min, bubble-sort

I had written this code.Its very buggy. I wanna have the order how i typed it in. Then sorted with bubblesort.And then the min and max values.The program gives me always the same min and max values.
Please help me.
Thx ;)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 10
int main()
{
int eingabe[N],mini,maxi,i,temp,j;
float medium,ds;
{
    printf("Bitte 10 Werte eingeben!");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%i",&eingabe[i]);
    }
    printf("Die eingegebenen Werte der Eingabereihenfolge nach:");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%i",eingabe[i]);
    }
    for(j=0;j<N-1;j++)
        for(i=0;i<N-1-j;i++)
        {
           if (eingabe[i]>eingabe[i+1])//Bubblesort

            {
                temp=eingabe[i];
                eingabe[i]=eingabe[i+1];//Tausch der Variablen
                eingabe[i+1]=temp;
            }



        }
    printf("Sortierte Werte(min to max):");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%i",eingabe[i]);
    }
    mini=eingabe[0];
    maxi=eingabe[0];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(maxi<eingabe[i])
        {
           maxi=eingabe[i];
        }
        if (eingabe[i]<mini)
        {
            mini=eingabe[i];
        }
    printf("\nDer Minimalwert ist: %i",mini);
    printf("\nDer Maximalwert ist: %i",maxi);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        medium=medium+eingabe[i];
    }
    ds=medium/2;
    printf("\nDer Durchschnitt betraegt: %f",ds);

    }



}
```

return 0;
}

Comment: the variables `mini` and `maxi` are initialized so you are testing value with anything. So it's dangerous!

Comment: Did you mean are *not* initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(maxi<eingabe[i])
        {
           maxi=eingabe[i];
        }
        if (eingabe[i]<mini)
        {
            mini=eingabe[i];
        }
```

here `maxi` and `mini` are not initialized so first comparison will not be fine. initialize those variables.
 you can initialize `mini` and `maxi` to `eingabe[0]`
You code for `bubble sort` is not complete.

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
           if (eingabe[i]>eingabe[i+1])

            {
                temp=eingabe[i];
                eingabe[i]=eingabe[i+1];
                eingabe[i+1]=temp;
            }

        }
```

there should be 2 for loops. one for loop means only one run through the array. it will not sort the array. the loops should be,

```
for(j=0;j<N-1;j++)
 for(i=0;i<N-1-j;i++)
 {
   //write the if statement

 }
```

in this part of code i think you are getting the min and max values

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(maxi<eingabe[i])
        {
           maxi=eingabe[i];
        }
        if (eingabe[i]<mini)
        {
            mini=eingabe[i];
        }
    printf("\nDer Minimalwert ist: %i",mini);
    printf("\nDer Maximalwert ist: %i",maxi);
```

change it to

```
mini=eingabe[0];
maxi=eingabe[0];
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(maxi<eingabe[i])
        {
           maxi=eingabe[i];
        }
        if (eingabe[i]<mini)
        {
            mini=eingabe[i];
        }
    }
    printf("\nDer Minimalwert ist: %i",mini);
    printf("\nDer Maximalwert ist: %i",maxi);
```

Comment: they are initialized on the top int line. Where i should initalize them?

Comment: @user3336852 They are *defined* on the first line but not initialized to any value. `int i;` will not initialize `i` to any particular value.

Comment: @user3336852 you can initialize min and max to eingabe[0]

Comment: like this:mini=eingabe[0];
        maxi=eingabe[0];
        for(i=0;i<N;i++) ?

Comment: @user3336852 ya. with that initialization try executing program. it should work.

Comment: @LearningC min and max are always the lowest number from bubblesort. :/

Comment: @user3336852 the for loop next to initialization should get the min and max value. i added code to answer check it

Comment: @LearningC i done it exactly like this. Same min and max output.:/ Look here(screenshot):http://gyazo.com/1d9777e8fc042076abe8d697150228ea (I edit my question to the actual code.pls check it again.;)) thx and best regards

Comment: @user3336852 the for loop should get the min and max values.add the print statements outside loop. the code that i posted in answer is fine. i think now program is working right

Answer (score 1):

```
eingabe[i]=eingabe[i+1];
                    ↑
```

`eingable` is of size `N`. And since arrays in C are *zero-based*, the indexes run from 0 to N - 1.
In the last iteration, your program tries to get the value n `eingabe[N]`, which is not available for it, so it crashes.

Also note that `mini` and `maxi` are *not* initialized and contain a garbage value, your program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    if (eingabe[i]>eingabe[i+1])
    {
        temp=eingabe[i];
        eingabe[i]=eingabe[i+1];
        eingabe[i+1]=temp;
    }
}
```

In this fragment, you are accessing out of bounds of the array. `N = 10`, that is the array size, when i becomes `9` i + 1 is 10, but accessing 10th index is undefined behaviour

Comment: [i-1] instead of [i+1]?

Comment: @user3336852 No, change the `for` loop to `for(i=0;i<N-1;i++)` after verifying that `N>0` holds.